# NetBeans некорректно отображает используемую память при профилировании

Tags: java, netbeans, профилирование

Начну сразу с изображения этой странной ошибки:
[image: Странный баг с профилированием в NetBeans]

Как видите, несмотря на то, что приложение потребляет свыше 3 ГБ оперативной памяти, NetBeans упорно показывает 200 МБ потребления.

В других проектах (и в этом в том числе, до недавнего времени) всё прекрасно работает.

Список испробованных мною мер:

- Возвращал вызывающий утечку памяти код и убирал его снова
- Очищал и собирал проект
- Запускал приложение без профилирования
- Убирал все вызовы функции System.out.println();

Ни одна из вышеперечисленных мер мне не помогла.

Используемая мною версия Netbeans - 8.1 (Сборка 201609300101)
Версия Java - 8.

Comment: А если собрать в jar ваш проект(ну или как там у вас он запускается без среды) и запустить вручную, что показывает диспетчер задач?

Comment: @VladVetrov, к сожалению, потребление осталось на таком же уровне.

Comment: @SOCIOPATH значит  дело не в Netbeans, а в вашей программе.